# VK API Wall.get не выдаёт предложку (suggests)

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, запрос

Здравствуйте, уважаемые знатоки! Вопрос такой: хочу получить через vkapi предложенные посты в моём тестовом паблике. Есть токен паблика и токен приложения, которое просто так было создано для запроса. Запрос типа wall.get

https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?owner_id=-162809646&count=100&filter=suggests&v=5.73&access_token= токен приложения.

Запрос выдаёт {"response":{"count":0,"items":[]}}.

Через сайт вк запрос работает, и выдаёт предложенный пост, а из php или адресной строки никак!( Так же пробовал варианты с токеном паблика(не сработало) и с двумя токенами сразу так же провал.

Comment: Как вариант, попробуйте убрать версию, очень часто и по сей день, это вызывает ошибки.

Comment: Спасибо за попытку...но версию я поставил сам!)) Response 0 был к сожалению и до этого..

Comment: сегодня что-то случилось в вк и запросы перестали работать без указания версии...все мои прошлые скрипты перестали работать сразу..так ладно это..думал версию поставю заработает...в итоге оказалось что и response перестал обрабатываться!